# Evaluating text in data table

Tags: r, eval, data.table

I'm trying to aggregate a lot of variables in a very large data table by a single variable. The issue I'm having is with `eval(parse(text=...))` which I believe is because I'm evaluating several expressions rather than just one. Here is a quick example:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
mtcars<-as.data.table(mtcars)

mtcars[,j=list(
  eval(parse(text='mean_mpg=mean(mpg),
             sum_mpg=sum(mpg)'))

),by=gear]

Error in parse(text = "mean_mpg=mean(mpg),\n             sum_mpg=sum(mpg)") : 
  <text>:1:19: unexpected ','
1: mean_mpg=mean(mpg),
```

The goal:

```
mtcars[,j=list(
  mean_mpg=mean(mpg),
  sum_mpg=sum(mpg)

),by=gear]
   gear mean_mpg sum_mpg
1:    4 24.53333   294.4
2:    3 16.10667   241.6
3:    5 21.38000   106.9
```

I'm going to be using this with `paste` but I thought it easier to read to write out this way.

Much thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do what you actually want. Can you please describe the goal instead of trying to use `eval`?

Comment: the goal is to be able to use a list of pre-defined variables in my data table and rather than write them all out one by one, efficiently paste and evaluate them or use some other method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make a lot of these variables at once is to leverage the `.SD` convenience variable.

Key variables to apply functions to:

```
key.vars <- c("mpg","disp","hp")
```

Extract `mean` and `sum` variables:

```
mtcars[, (c(paste0("mean_",key.vars),paste0("sum_",key.vars))) := 
          c(lapply(.SD,mean),lapply(.SD,sum)), 
          by=gear, .SDcols=key.vars]
```

Result:

```
head(mtcars)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mean_mpg mean_disp  mean_hp sum_mpg sum_disp sum_hp
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 24.53333  123.0167  89.5000   294.4   1476.2   1074
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 24.53333  123.0167  89.5000   294.4   1476.2   1074
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 24.53333  123.0167  89.5000   294.4   1476.2   1074
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 16.10667  326.3000 176.1333   241.6   4894.5   2642
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 16.10667  326.3000 176.1333   241.6   4894.5   2642
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 16.10667  326.3000 176.1333   241.6   4894.5   2642
```

If you don't want to append to the current table, you can use this, similar code:

```
output <- mtcars[, c(lapply(.SD,mean),lapply(.SD,sum)), by=gear, .SDcols=key.vars]
setnames(output,c("gear",c(paste0("mean_",key.vars),paste0("sum_",key.vars))))
output
```

Result:

```
   gear mean_mpg mean_disp  mean_hp sum_mpg sum_disp sum_hp
1:    4 24.53333  123.0167  89.5000   294.4   1476.2   1074
2:    3 16.10667  326.3000 176.1333   241.6   4894.5   2642
3:    5 21.38000  202.4800 195.6000   106.9   1012.4    978
```

I am not sure exactly what you are wanting to do, but I think it is easiest to work with aggregated data that is long as opposed to wide e.g.

```
sum.list <- lapply(key.vars, function(x) mtcars[, .(Var=x,Mean=mean(get(x)),Sum=sum(get(x))), by=gear])
sum.table <- rbindlist(sum.list,fill=T)
sum.table
```

Result:

```
   gear  Var      Mean    Sum
1:    4  mpg  24.53333  294.4
2:    3  mpg  16.10667  241.6
3:    5  mpg  21.38000  106.9
4:    4 disp 123.01667 1476.2
5:    3 disp 326.30000 4894.5
6:    5 disp 202.48000 1012.4
7:    4   hp  89.50000 1074.0
8:    3   hp 176.13333 2642.0
9:    5   hp 195.60000  978.0
```

Seems a bit easier to work with.

Comment: This is really close. I don't want to append to my data.table, I just want a print out of the aggregations like I showed in "my goal"

Comment: Edited to not append and also added another example